# CMake find_library not finding TensorFlow library

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, cmake

My CMakeLists.txt includes the following lines:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "python" "-c" "import tensorflow as tf; print tf.sysconfig.get_lib()" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TF_LIB_DIR)

find_library(TF_LIB 
    NAMES tensorflow_framework 
    PATHS ${TF_LIB_DIR}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Unfortunately - the tensorflow library is not found. This is confirmed by doing:
`message(STATUS ${TF_LIB})` which prints out `TF_LIB-NOTFOUND`.

TF_LIB_DIR is set to `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow` by the `execute_process` call.

The contents of this directory is `aux-bin  contrib  core  examples  include  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  libtensorflow_framework.so  python  tools`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you guess in your answer, your problem is a trailing newline at the end of the path. Referenced question describes how to strip it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the execute_process call with:

`execute_process(COMMAND "python" "-c" "import tensorflow as tf; import sys; sys.stdout.write(tf.sysconfig.get_lib() + '/')" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TF_LIB_DIR)`

I believe the problem was either the lack of path separator or the trailing newline that was written into OUTPUT_VARIABLE due to the python print statement appending a newline.

Comment: Seems a bit shorter:

execute_process(COMMAND "python" "-c" "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TF_INC)

include_directories(${TF_INC})